# Smooth javascript progress bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a js progress bar which finishes after 5 seconds and then runs some code.

What I have from w3:

```js
var i = 0;
function move() {
  if (i == 0) {
    i = 1;
    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
    var width = 1;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
    function frame() {
      if (width >= 100) {
        clearInterval(id);
        i = 0;
      } else {
        width++;
        elem.style.width = width + "%";
      }
    }
  }
}

move();
```

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

#myBar {
  width: 1%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>
```

How can I f.e. adjust its time to 5 seconds, with the animation still being smooth?

Comment: `setInterval(..., (5 * 1000) / 100)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The animation need not be done in javascript. Use CSS instead for smoother performance and cleaner code.

It's generally a better idea to use CSS animations over JS, especially when they are simple. You should read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/CSS_JavaScript_animation_performance). If you still want to do it in javascript for some reason, you should use this dedicated call for animating stuff [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

```js
function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
  
  myBar.style.width = "0%";
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    myBar.style.width = "100%";
  });
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    alert("done");
    /* do stuff */
  }, 5000);
}

move();
```

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

#myBar {
  width: 0%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
  transition: width 5s linear; /* note this line */
}
```

```html
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For higher quality animations is better to use `requestAnimationFrame`.

```js
let start;
let element = document.getElementById("myBar");
let count = 0;
function step(timestamp) {
  if (start === undefined)
    start = timestamp;
  const elapsed = timestamp - start;

  element.style.width = (100 / 2000) * elapsed + "%";
  
  if (elapsed < 2000) { // Stop the animation after 2 seconds
    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
  }else {
  }
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
```

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

#myBar {
  width: 1%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `var id = setInterval(frame, 10);` 1000 = 1 second

```js
var i = 0;
function move() {
  if (i == 0) {
    i = 1;
    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
    var width = 1;
    var id = setInterval(frame, (5*1000)/100);
    function frame() {
      if (width >= 100) {
        clearInterval(id);
        i = 0;
      } else {
        width++;
        elem.style.width = width + "%";
      }
    }
  }
}

move();
```

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

#myBar {
  width: 1%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to divide this value by 100 becouse this way it change this bar by 1% every 5 sec

Answer (score 0):

[According to docs setInterval `delay` param is in miliseconds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

> **delayOptional** The time, in milliseconds (thousandths of a second), the
> timer should delay in between executions of the specified function or
> code. See Delay restrictions below for details on the permitted range
> of delay values.

```js
var i = 0;
const element = document.getElementById("myBar");
let width = 1;
let chunk = 100 / 5;

function move() {
  if (i == 0) {
        
    let handle = setInterval(frame, 1000);
    
    function frame() {
      if (width >= 100) {
        clearInterval(handle);
      } else {
        width = width + chunk;
        element.style.width = `${width}%`;
      }
    }
  }
}

move();
```

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

#myBar {
  width: 0%;
  transition: all .3s ease-in;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var i = 0;
function move() {
  if (i == 0) {
    i = 1;
    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
    var width = 1;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 5000/100);
    function frame() {
      if (width >= 100) {
        clearInterval(id);
        i = 0;
      } else {
        width++;
        elem.style.width = width + "%";
      }
    }
  }
}

move();
```

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

#myBar {
  width: 1%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>
```

basicly time you want divided by count of how many loops it take to fill whole bar